# PHP Date/Time - If "Day = X" and "Time is between 18 and 21" echo

Tags: php, date, if-statement, time, echo

I have a radio schedule and what I'd like to do is have specific text displayed as bold when a show is live, and displayed as normal when not live.

Shows are on set days of the week and at set times during that day.

e.g.

- 'Show 1' is on Friday from 18:00-21:00.
- 'Show 2' is on Friday from 21:00-22:00.
- 'Show 3' is on Friday from 22:00-00:00.
- 'Show 4' is on Saturday from 00:00-06:00.

and so on.

So if its 19:00 on Friday, 'Show 1' is in bold.

My appalling first effort at learning looked like this. Clearly it lacks the time ranges and stuff but it worked at least as long as the current hour was 18:00. How do I expand this to work if the time is between a range from 18:00-21:00 AND the day is Friday? I can extrapolate out the rest of the days/times from one example :D

```
if( date( 'H' ) == 18 and date( 'w' ) == 5)
{
echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Show 1</span>';
}
else 
{ 
echo 'Show 1';
}
```

Thanks in advance, I are stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display the show in bold based on the time ranges.

```
$hour = date('H');
$day = date('w');
$shows = array(
    "",
    "Show 1",
    "Show 2",
    "Show 3",
    "Show 4",
);

$show = 0;
if($hour >= 18 && $hour < 21 && $day == 5) { $show = 1; }
if($hour >= 21 && $hour < 22 && $day == 5) { $show = 2; }
if($hour >= 22 && $hour < 24 && $day == 5) { $show = 3; }
if($hour >= 0 && $hour < 6 && $day == 6) { $show = 4; }

for($i = 0; $i < count($shows); $i++){
    if($show == $i) { echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$shows[$i].'</span>'; 
    } else { echo '<span>'.$shows[$i].'</span>'; }
    echo "<br>";
}
```